# Using GNU screen, I get raw prompt with backslashes

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, prompt

When I use the `screen` program, the prompt doesn't get interpreted and is just the following:

```
\u@\h:\w$
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`screen` is running `dash` or other shell which doesn't recognize those bash-specific prompt escapes inside `PS1`.

Either set the `SHELL` environment variable to `/bin/bash` before starting `screen`, run it as `screen -s /bin/bash` or set the following in your `~/.screenrc`:

```
shell /bin/bash
```

The `~/.screenrc` command has precedence over the `-s` command line switch, which has precedence over the `$SHELL` envvar. If neither is set `/bin/sh` will be used.